# Error while i return from controller a view in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, optional-parameters

I have a method in my controller which takes as OPTIONAL parameter a bool variable(this should be optional not mandatory) although when I return the view it says that the view expects a parameter.

I have my modelview which sets the bool to true or false in order to display an error message in the view if a certain action did happen.

here is my code

```
    public ActionResult Index([Optional] bool cameFromModal)
    {cameFromModal = false;
         if (cameFromModal == true)
              {
            vm.Error = true; // I set the bool to the model so that I can                       display an error message on my returned view
              }


        return View(vm);
    }
```

Comment: I've not used the `[Optional]` attribute on an MVC controller method before.  What happens when you change the method signature so that the param is nullable instead?  `public ActionResult Index(bool? cameFromModal)`

Comment: Post the actual error. What does `it says that the view expects a parameter.` mean? That's neither a compilation nor a runtime error. Where is `vm` created? The `Optional` attribute in the request parameters doesn't affect the view or controller code

Comment: As for `cameFromModal` you don't specify a default value so there's no way the compiler knows what value to use. `Optional` is a validation attribute, it doesn't specify what the default value is

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can try this;

```
public ActionResult Index(bool cameFromModal=false)
{             
if (cameFromModal == true)
{
vm.Error = true;
}
return View(vm);
}
```

when you trigger true its come to error